# Box2d Lighting different behavior with different screen size

Tags: java, libgdx, light, box2dlights

I tried to play a little with lighting, but very quickly I came upon weird behavior that I dont understand. Could anybody explain to me, why this happens, if it is on purpose, or I do something wrong.

On the first image, light goes little trough obstacle (which is also weird).

[image: Game screen wider]

When the screen size is changed to lower width, the light goes even more through obstacle.

The red background is "black bar", since I use FitViewport. The "real" world has badlogic.jpg all over it.

[image: Game screen narrow]

On the next pictures you can see, how it works without light rendering - the screen renders the same world regardless of screen size (only scaled). Thats how I would expect it to work even with lighting.

[image]

[image]

The project is standard, generated by libgdx project generator. All my code is just one class, so I can upload it here:

```
package com.gobanit.sandbox.main;

import com.badlogic.ashley.core.Engine;
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.CircleShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;

import box2dLight.PointLight;
import box2dLight.RayHandler;

public class SandboxTestGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    World world;
    Engine engine;
    Viewport viewport;
    Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;
    Texture texture;
    RayHandler rayHandler;

    Body playerBody;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg"));
        engine = new Engine();
        world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), true);
        viewport = new FitViewport(1000, 500);
        viewport.getCamera().position.set(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
        debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();   
        rayHandler = new RayHandler(world);
        rayHandler.setShadows(true);

        createPlayerBody();
        createObstacleBody();       

        PointLight l1 = new PointLight(rayHandler, 100, null, 500, 0, 0);
        l1.attachToBody(playerBody);
        //l1.setSoft(true);

        //new PointLight(rayHandler, 100, null, 500, 0, 200);

    }

    private void createObstacleBody() {
        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.position.add(new Vector2(-10000, 100));
        bodyDef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;

        Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

        FixtureDef fixDef = new FixtureDef();
        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.set(new float[] {0f,0f,0f,40f,20000f,40f,20000f,0f});
        fixDef.shape = shape;

        body.createFixture(fixDef);

        body.setActive(true);       
    }

    private void createPlayerBody() {
        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.position.add(new Vector2(100, 50));
        bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;

        Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

        FixtureDef fixDef = new FixtureDef();
        CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
        circle.setRadius(20);
        fixDef.shape = circle;

        body.createFixture(fixDef);

        body.setActive(true);

        playerBody = body;      
    }



    @Override
    public void render () {
        update();
        draw();
    }

    private void draw() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(100, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        viewport.update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(viewport.getCamera().combined);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(texture, -1000, -1000, 2000, 2000);
        batch.end();

        debugRenderer.render(world, viewport.getCamera().combined);

        rayHandler.setCombinedMatrix((OrthographicCamera) viewport.getCamera());
        rayHandler.render();    
    }

    private void update() {
        world.step(1f/60f, 8, 3);
        rayHandler.update();

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D)) {
            //viewport.getCamera().position.add(new Vector3(1,0,0));
            playerBody.applyForceToCenter(100, 0, true);
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)) {
            //viewport.getCamera().position.add(new Vector3(-1,0,0));
            playerBody.applyForceToCenter(-100, 0, true);
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W)) {
            //viewport.getCamera().position.add(new Vector3(0,1,0));
            playerBody.applyForceToCenter(0, 100, true);
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.S)) {
            //viewport.getCamera().position.add(new Vector3(0,-1,0));
            playerBody.applyForceToCenter(0, -100, true);
        }   

        viewport.getCamera().position.set(new Vector3(playerBody.getPosition().x, playerBody.getPosition().y, 0));
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
        texture.dispose();
        world.dispose();
        debugRenderer.dispose();
        rayHandler.dispose();
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot. If more information is needed, tell me and I will edit the question.

Comment: box2dlights doesn't retrieve the viewport automatically - which seems to change in your examples provided, whenever viewport is updated try calling the rayHandler.useCustomViewport(x,y,w,h) method. You can find just a few more info on [box2dlights wiki here](https://github.com/libgdx/box2dlights/wiki/Custom-viewport-and-box2dlights).

Comment: Yeah, that solved it! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Nice that you could solve it. Maybe Mikhail or yourself answers that question and you accept this answer...

Answer (score 0):

[image: useCustomViewport function in the documentation]

to confirm what @Mikhail Churbanov said and bring more visibility. The documentation mention that it is our responsibility to update the viewport on resize. I thought it was the point of the fit viewport. I am confused.

Anyway, i ended up using this function in my resize() like the following :

```
    if(viewport.getRightGutterWidth() > 0){
        rayHandler.useCustomViewport(viewport.getRightGutterWidth()-5,viewport.getBottomGutterHeight()-5, (int)(height*SCREEN_RATIO)+10,height+10);
    }else{
        rayHandler.useCustomViewport(viewport.getRightGutterWidth()-5,viewport.getBottomGutterHeight()-5, width+10,(int)(width/SCREEN_RATIO)+10);
    }
```

- The first condition allow to differentiate from a vertical/horizontal resize
- using getRightGutterWidth and getBottomGutterHeight to position the viewport
- Using the ratio of the screen constant to deduce the width or height depending on the case
- Last but not least, sadly had to add a tiny padding (5s & 10s) otherwise you would sometime see a 1px line on the viewport without the light applied.

Doing so give me mixed vibes. I don't give much confidence that's the way to do, but hey, it works !